# Doubts on some results: from raytracing to distributed raytracing

Tags: graphics, sampling, raytracing

I have a simple ray tracer that I did some time ago. What I am trying to do now is improving it and transforming it in a distributed ray tracer. The first thing I am doing is shooting a bunch of rays instead of a single ray through each pixel. Each ray of my bunch is slightly jittered from the center of the relative pixel. The final color of the pixel is then decided as average of the results given by those rays. What I want to ask you is if the results I am having are correct and the reasons why they are correct or if there is something wrong. Below you can find some pics:

Normal RayTracing:

[image]

Distributed RayTracing with 10 rays through each pixel:

[image]

Distributed RayTracing with 10 rays through each pixel and light increased:

[image]

So my questions are:

1) is it normal that the I need to increase the intensity of my light when I switch from 1 to 10 rays?

2) is the result in the third picture a reasonable one?

I guess it is wrong for a reason: I have similar result if instead of using 10 rays I use only 1, but always jittered from the center. See picture below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Distributed raytracing isn't about shooting multiple rays per pixel. A pixel is very small, shooting 10 rays through it has no significant effect on the image. In distributed raytracing, multiple rays are shot from the points of intersections for simulating soft shadow, motion blur, glossy reflection etc. The jitter you're adding to the rays through the pixels should actually be applied to the  shadow rays.

> 1) is it normal that the I need to increase the intensity of my light when I switch from 1 to 10 rays?

It depends on how you're combining the colors from each ray. If you calculate the illumination for each ray and average them, the pixel should not be so dark.

> 2) is the result in the third picture a reasonable one?

I think it is more aliased than than the one generated by shooting single ray.

Comment: Ok.. I have been reading around that the first feature characterizing a distributed ray tracing is the anti-aliasing effect. In order to obtain that I had to launch in each pixel a bunch of rays instead of a single ray. Each ray thrown through the center of the pixel jittered a little bit by random dx and dy.. I wanted to implement step by step every feature.. anti-aliasing, soft shadows, motion blur etc.. so the first one I was aiming for was indeed the anti-aliasing effect.. but it seems I failed.. what do you think is the problem in my renderer?

Comment: How are you 'mixing' the colors returned from the jittered rays?

Comment: With a simple average. I sum the results given by each single ray and then divide the final sum for the number of rays. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does the object you are using to store colour have a limited range? If it is (such as a colour with 8 bit per channel), accumulating the 10 rays will make it max out, then dividing by 10 will result in dark colours. You could either divide each ray by 10 before adding them, or use a colour class that allows greater range (float colour with no clamping to 1.0, etc).